# Elasticsearch complex filter

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I use elasticsearch search to retrieve some doc and I would like to do a simple statement like:

```
if ((a == "1" || b == "2") || (c == "3" && d == "4"))
```

I use the first statement ((a == "1" || b == "2")) with that

```
$filter ['bool'] ['must'] [] = array (
  'bool' => array (
    'should' => array (
      array (
        'terms' => array (
          'a' => $aName
        ) 
      ),
      array (
        'terms' => array (
          'b' => $bName
        ) 
      ),
    ),           
  ) 
);
```

But after I'm lost. I don't know how I can add:

```
(c == "3" && d == "4")
```

Comment: Don't you already have that in the if statement above?

Comment: i don't understand the if statement is an example of what i would like to do

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Nesting Boolean Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#_nesting_boolean_filters). For your case, I believe something like this would work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "a": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "term": {
                          "b": 2
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "c": 3
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "d": 4
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Converting it back to php should be easy from here.